# git api to manipulate on Java

Tags: java, git, github-api

I would like to build an application that in each time the developer commit in a git, I receive feedback for that commit: time of the commit, details about the commit (JSON format), and the comment in the commit.
I'm a beginner in Git API manipulation. I would like to know how to manipulate the GIT API to know information about every commits in the GitHub repository.
Any suggestion will be very appreciated!!

Comment: You would need to look into the concept of "hooks" on the git server side, or their equivalent on GitHub. Hooks are executed when certain things are happening, e.g. a user has pushed changes to a git repo.

Comment: I don't think you need to do any coding for this at all. There is tons of services that offer this kind of integration with Github (maybe the notifications that Github itself provides are already enough).

Comment: there is a webhook for the git server side. Did u used before StefanBecker? because I looked for an exemple but I couldn't find one.I mean how the get the API?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
1. Jgit.
link:
https://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Appendix-B%3A-Embedding-Git-in-your-Applications-JGit

2.GitHub API for Java
link:https://github-api.kohsuke.org/